# How to divide a number in range(1,16) from all elements in a list NumList = [2,4]

Tags: python

I have a list `NumList = [2,4]` and an integer ex. 16. I want to find all the elements in `range(1,16)` that are divisible by both 2 and 4 in NumList.

I tried the code and searched on the internet but couldn't get satisfactory results. Kindly help. Please Don't criticize if its basic. I am new to programming and not very much familiar with these fundamentals.

Code:-

```
fact = list()

for i in range(1,16):
    for x in a:
        num = i % x
        if num == 0:
            fact.append(i)

print(fact)
```

Output:-
[2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 8, 10, 12, 12, 14]. Where am i wrong?

Comment: The problem is you are adding the number if it's divisible by either of the values in `a`. You want to add a check to make sure that it's divisible by both. Your inner loop can be eliminated and replaced with `if all((i%x)==0 for x in a): fact.append(i)` but at that point your can replace your whole code with the one line: `fact = [i for i in range(1, 16) if all((i%x)==0 for x in a)]`

Comment: I got that after seeing answers. I was doing a logical mistake.Thank You for pointing out and explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) function from the standard library and `%` [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operators#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the ZeroDivisionError exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., 3.14%0.7 equals 0.34 (since 3.14 equals 4*0.7 + 0.34.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand

```
l = [3, 4, 5]

for num in range(1, 250):
    if all(num % x == 0 for x in l):
        print(num)
```

will print:

```
60
120
180
240
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers that are divisible by all values in NumList will be multiples of the LCM of these values (Least Common Multiple).  The math module provides a gcd() function which can be used to compute the LCM of two numbers `LCM(a,b) = a*b/gcd(a,b)`.

So, if you first compute the LCM of all numbers in NumList, you can then use a striding range to directly get the multiples you're looking for:

```
numList = [2,4]
maxNum  = 16

from math import gcd
LCM       = 1
for n in numList: LCM = LCM*n//gcd(LCM,n)
multiples = list(range(LCM,maxNum+1,LCM))

print(multiples) # [4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Note that this will run much faster than the modulo techniques when the numbers in numList are large:

For example:

```
numList = [295243, 2975141]
maxNum  = 270737831
```

The LCM multiples approach produces the result instantly (as opposed to the modulo loops which would take a long time)

```
# [38676833, 77353666, 116030499, 154707332, 193384165, 232060998, 270737831]
```

If you don't want to use the math module, you can write your own `gcd()` and `lcm()` functions and use them like this:

```
def gcd(a,b):    return b if a == 0 else gcd(b%a,a)
def lcm(a,b,*c): return a*b//gcd(a,b) if not c else lcm(lcm(a,b),*c)

numList   = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
maxNum    = 70000000    
LCM       = lcm(*numList)
multiples = list(range(LCM,maxNum+1,LCM))

# [9699690, 19399380, 29099070, 38798760, 48498450, 58198140, 67897830]
```

*Note that recursion in lcm() eliminates the for loops and is only applied to the values in numList. The overall performance will be proportional to the number of factors in numList rather than a multiple of maxNum.*

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using loop

```
l=16

numlist=[2,5]
divlist=[]

for i in range(1,l):
    a=0
    for item in numlist:
        if(i%item==0):
            a +=1
            if(a==len(numlist)):
                divlist.append(i)                

print(divlist)
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect. Check it on `numList = [2, 5]`.

Comment: @vurmux oh my bad for using loop i have to put another check but your way is more effective btw thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the list you can test if the sum of the modulus of each element is zero:

```
n = [2, 4]
r = range(1,16) 
[num for num in r if not sum([num % j for j in n])]

# [4, 8, 12]
```

Comment: I was not able to understand this part:- if not sum([num % j for j in n])]. Can you please elaborate sir.

Comment: @Ankit `num % j ` will return a  0 when the `num` is divisible. `[num % j for j in n]` will be a list of all the modulus. If every number in `n` is divisible by `j` this will be a list of zeros like `[0, 0, 0]`. That means the sum will be zero if and only if all the numbers are divisible.